# Can't Access Single User Mode

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu, single-user

My DGPU is shot on my late 2011 MacBook Pro 17", and I want to disable it from single-user mode. The problem is that holding down CMD + S doesn't open single-user mode, and the laptop won't boot to the OS. I currently have Windows 10 installed on it, and it doesn't get past the boot throbber.

Much obliged.